# Event for select box dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `select` element like so:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

What I want is an event to be triggered each time the `select` box is dropped down to display the options, and then another event to be triggered when the opposite happens.

I tried this:

```
$("select").click(function () {
    $("#textMe").val("open");
});

$("select").change(function() {
    $("#textMe").val("closed");
});
```

But I have a couple problems:

1. If the user does actually select an `option` for some reason it seems like my `change` event never fires - why?
2. If the user opened the select box, but then clicked elsewhere on their page to close the select box (they didn't actually select an option, thus nothing was changed) I'm not sure how to trap that event.

---

Here is a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38VGV/3/)**.

Comment: Another option would be to implement a pseudo select control built from a div and a textbox that throws an event in this situation. A bit of a pain, but there is probably a jQuery plugin out there that does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that easy in your case but you could do the following to capture all needed events:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38VGV/7/)

```
var opened = false;

$("select").on("click", function () {
    if(!opened){
        $("#textMe").val("open");
        opened = true;
    }
});

$("select").on("change", function() {
    $("#textMe").val("change");

    setTimeout(function(){
        opened = false;
    },0);
});

$("body").on("click", function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is("select")) {
        $("#textMe").val("OUTSIDE");
        opened = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Just changed my selected answer to this

Answer (score 2):

There are no events specifically for a `select` expand or collapse. You cannot rely on focus or blur alone, nor on click. Your best way to go about it is to implement it manually i.e.

1. capture Click event of select
2. capture Change event of select
3. capture Click event on 'document minus select' separately
4. maintain a global variable to determine whether select itself is clicked to expand or has been clicked again to collapse.

this all depends on how neatly you consider all the possible forms of interaction with your select and what should happen in each case.

Another, a little lengthy approach can be to get rid of html `select` altogether, create your own `dropdown-like` group of elements i.e. a textbox, which flashes a hidden div as you begin to type on it or click on it, just like any of those customized dropdowns (i.e. bootstrap-select), there you can very easily attach any trigger or event on expansion and collapse, (but i guess it will be a little overkill :D)